# Knowing if a remote port forward was successful?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access, portforwarding

I am trying to setup some reverse ssh tunnels so I can access my home network by bouncing off some server with a public IP.

When I run this command:
ssh -R :[port_XX]:localhost:22 some_user@my_server

Even if "port_XX" is in use, it will still make a successful ssh connection to "my_server".

If I am running this command directly, I can see the problem when it gives me a warning:
"Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port [port_XX]"

However, I am starting this ssh session **inside a screen session** using a cron job.

**How can I programmatically check if the remote port forwarding was successful?**

The screen session can be checked with "screen -ls", the ssh session is also easily checked, but the remote port forwarding...?

(Please let me know if this question is not clear enough! I've done my research but haven't found a simple solution.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`

The full command will be something like:

```
ssh -N -R [port_XX]:localhost:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes user@host
```

(`-N` is useful to just forward port, without opening a remote shell; you can also add `-f` to send process in background, no need if you are running under screen, though..)

Comment: Ah hah! I knew there was a simple way to do it. I was looking through the options but couldn't find a good example of how to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Question: Without this option, is the tunnel that is left behind after the forwarding failure useful for anything, or is it just dead?