# ssh process is still created even when I get bind: Address already in use

Tags: linux, ssh

I am running following ssh command :

```
ssh -i deploy.pem -f -N -L  3307:127.0.0.1:3306 ubuntu@192.168.33.44
```

If I run this command twice it gives error :

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3307
Could not request local forwarding.
```

And exits (or not ) . The error is obvious but I am not understanding why it spawns new process and wait on unavailable port . What I expected was if port is not available it should just exit with and error . But my `ps ax | grep ssh|grep -v grep` showing increasing number of process with each try.

So the question is how to tell ssh that just exit if port is not available or fails to connect to host. Pardon me if this is so obvious.

Comment: try `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514040/knowing-if-a-remote-port-forward-was-successful

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: I've removed [tag:bash].